# Netbeans how to restore the compile errors popup

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

This is a pretty silly situation, but I accidentally disabled the "One or more projects were compiled with errors" popup because I hit enter whilst selecting the wrong thing. I like the popup as it is a clear indication that something isn't correct before the program runs, is there any way to restore the popup?

This isn't a really big issue or anything, I was just wondering if anybody could give any pointers as to where the option is located.

Thanks :)

Picture of the popup:

[image: Here is a picture of the popup]

Answer (score 0):

try

***User made a lot of changes to the toolbar layout and added/removed a lot of buttons and now he/she wants to reset the toolbars to their default settings. The default settings are the toolbar layout and content as on the first IDE startup.**

Scenario:
User right-clicks an empty area in the toolbar row to open popup menu.
User selects Reset Toolbars item in the popup menu and all toolbars are restored to their default settings.

Alternate Scenario:
User selects main menu View - Toolbars.
User selects Reset Toolbars item in the popup menu and all toolbars are restored to their default settings.

Alternate Scenario - Using Customize Toolbars window:
User invokes Customize Toolbars window - either from the toolbar popup menu or from the main menu View - Toolbars - Customize.
User clicks Reset Toolbars button and all toolbars are restored to their default settings.*

[see this](https://core.netbeans.org/proposals/reset-settings-ui-spec.html)

Comment: That link only refers to toolbars and palette settings, it doesn't detail how to restore error popups :/

Comment: Option is to restore netbeans to default setting